# React/Redux how to pass argument to modify API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have been using Redux for the past two days, i'm getting to understand it more, however I  encountered a problem which has stopped my progress.

I have an API which has interchangeable parameters.

e.g. `api.example.com/data/{date}/..` and `api.example.com/more-data/{regId}/..`

My `<Picker />` selects a value and that value should be passed to the URL, which calls the API and gives the selected data; in my case `regionId`.

The problem is changing the params without causing errors or getting CORS problem with the Api call. I also want to be able to set the `regionId` to have an initialState, so I can begin the request with a parameter in the url.

ReqService.js (just for async api calling)

```
class ReqService {
    async getRequest(url) {
        try {
            let response = await (await fetch(url));
            let responseJson = await response.json();
            return responseJson;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error: ', error);
        }
    }
}
export default new ReqService()
```

actions.js

```
import ReqService from '../ReqService';

export const IS_FETCHING = 'IS_FETCHING';
export const DATA_FETCHED = 'DATA_FETCHED';
export const ERROR_FETCHING_DATA = 'ERROR_FETCHING_DATA';

const BASE_URL = 'https://api.example.com/';
const DATE_TODAY = new Date().toISOString();

export const getTheData = (regionId) => { 
  // The regionId is the param i want to pass to the url
  const url = `${BASE_URL}/${DATE_TODAY}/${regionId}`;
  const request = ReqService.getRequest(url);

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: IS_FETCHING });
    request
      .then((data ) => {
        dispatch({ type: DATA_FETCHED, payload: data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_FETCHING_DATA, payload: error });
      });
  };
};
```

reducer.js

```
import { IS_FETCHING, DATA_FETCHED, ERROR_FETCHING_DATA } from '../Actions/actions';

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  error: null
};

export const myReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case IS_FETCHING:
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case DATA_FETCHED:
      console.log('The Data Fetched ', action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        fetched: true,
        fetching: false,
        data: action.payload.data
      };
    case ERROR_FETCHING_DATA:
      return { ...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload.error };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The component where the param changes here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View, Text, Picker} from 'react-native'
import { connect } from '../../node_modules/react-redux';
import { getTheData } from './Actions/actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class FrontPage extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      regionId:0
    };
  }

  changeRegion = (regId) => {
    this.props.getTheData(regId);
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Front Page</Text>
        <Picker selectedValue={this.props.regionId}
                    onValueChange={itemValue => this.changeRegion(itemValue)}>
                    <Picker.Item label="One" value='1' />
                    <Picker.Item label="Two" value='2' />
                </Picker>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.data,
    fetching: state.fetching,
    error: state.error
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ getTheData }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FrontPage);
```

I dont know if I am doing this correct, I looked at different examples and implemented what seems right. Any help will be great.

Comment: Thanks for publishing this! There's not many resources on this redux topic, they have made it insanely hard to figure this stuff out.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are sharing it looks like a good implementation of React and Redux.

If you'd like the Picker component initially have a selected value, then set your state to what it should be. In your case, set the state regionId in your `FrontPage` component.

```
this.state = {
  regionId: 1 // this will pre-select the first value.
};
```

*"The problem is changing the params without causing errors or getting CORS problem with the Api call."*

I'm unsure which problems you have when the params are changed. Can you elaborate or include a screenshot?

As for the CORS error message. Have a look at the article [How to fix CORS problems](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/) to gain a better understanding of it and what you need to change. When getting this error the problem isn’t in the client application but in the server application. To fix it, you need to enable CORS support at the server level.
You can do this by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. e.g.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will allow any host to access the API, even when they are on a different domain or post.

Comment: Before implementing Redux I didn't have CORS problem, but I think the way I'm calling/changing the URL is causing a problem. That`s why I think I may have did this wrong. But i'm gonna do more testing tomorrow. But for now I'll probably read up on CORS. Thanks for the advice though. +1

Comment: The way you create the API url looks good from what you've shared. If you can share the error messages you are getting I can tweak my answer to that. I'll keep an eye out on your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the question with the error message tomorrow hopefully, I'm also using redux logger which I'll show too.